# How to resolve Cloud Function Error:401 Unauthorized

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-cloud-functions, google-calendar-api

I have coded an Apps Script that creates an event in the Calendar.
Apps Script is stand alone, and event in also created in my personal Gmail account.
This Script is linked to GCP project linked to same account as Script.
Oauth consent screen is created in the GCP account and also credentials for Oauth2.0 client ID.
Now I created a cloud function to call this appsScript but it is giving an Error:401
following is code for the cloud function

````
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';

const axios = require('axios');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

//Authorization
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');
const auth1 = new GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: 'credentials.json',
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
        , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events' ],
    });

const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: auth1 });
const calendar = google.calendar({version : "v3"});

//calling formSchedule function with all the variables

async function formSchedule(eventDate,claimId, garageId, claimDet,startTime,cEmailG){
    
        //Schedule Meeting Json Data
      
        var evDurtion=30;    
        var startDateTime = startTime;
        var endDateTime=new Date(startDateTime.getTime()+(evDurtion*60000));
        // console.log(endDateTime)
        var subject="Claim ID : "+claimId+' - Call';
        
        var attendees=[{
          "email": garageId,
          },
        ];
        var eventData={
          "summary":subject, 
          'start': {
            'dateTime': startDateTime,
            'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
          },
          'end': {
            'dateTime': endDateTime,
            'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
          },
          "attendees":attendees,
          "conferenceData": {
            "createRequest": {
              "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
              },
              "status": {
                "statusCode": "success"
              },
              "requestId": "test1235"
            }
          },
          "description":claimDet,
          "defaultReminders": [
            {
              "method": "popup",
              "minutes": "5"
            }
          ]
        }
        console.log("after all variables initialization")
        // Schedule Meeting 
        axios({
          method: "post",
          url : //API Executable deployed Apps Script link,
          data: {
              'eventdata' : eventData,
              'serviceId' : cEmailG
          },
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
          },
        }).then(function (response) {
            try{
              console.log('Event Added Successfully.')
            }
            catch (error){
              console.log('------error-----',error)
            }
          })
    }

       
  res.status(200).send(message);
};```
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About `url : //API Executable deployed Apps Script link,`, in your situation, which do you want to use the scripts.run method of Google Apps Script API or Web Apps?

Comment: please include the full error message.   Just curious can you load credentials.json into a cloud function?

Comment: Yes @DalmTo I am able to load credentials.json file.. It is included in the same folder as index.js and package.js

Comment: @Tanaike I am sorry if I am unable to explain my query, I am really new to stackoverflow, by the way here I am using Google Apps Script API.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that you are trying to run the Google Apps Script by giving the values to Google Apps Script using Google Apps Script API. In this case, before your script is modified, I'm worried whether your setting for using Google Apps Script API is correct. When you simply tested it, could you obtain the result you expect? I apologize for this question.